# Redis on Docker: Error 111 connecting to 0.0.0.0:6379. Connection refused

Tags: python, django, docker, redis

Python and Redis work fine together in my local. I try to dockerize the project.

When I **docker-compose up**, redis container works fine.

```
> Server initialized
> Ready to accept connections
```

But when I call a request in POSTMAN, I get the following error:

```
Error 111 connecting to 0.0.0.0:6379. Connection refused.
```

My settings:

```
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": "redis://0.0.0.0:6379/1",
        "OPTIONS": {
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
        }
    }
}
```

My docker-compose.yml:

```
redis:
    image: bitnami/redis:latest
    volumes:
      - ./redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

...and in Dockerfile:

```
ENV REDIS_URL=redis://0.0.0.0:6379/1
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use `bitnami/redis:latest` for redis setup, so you surely have another service in `docker-compose.yaml` to define your django application, then link to that `redis` container.

The problem is here, you use `redis://0.0.0.0:6379/1` to connect to the `redis` container from your `django` container, it's not correct.

In fact, if you not define any customized network in your compose file, all container will be in a default network, which means your `django` container can directly visit your `redis` container with service name.

In one word, you should change

```
redis://0.0.0.0:6379/1
```

to

```
redis://redis:6379/1
```

You may want to have a look for [Networing in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

Additional, as you expose `6379`, so change `0.0.0.0` to your docker host's ip could be another option.

Comment: Thank you, so you say remove ENV from Dockerfile and change CACHES variable in my settings?

Comment: Use `ENV` or `variable in CACHES` is dependent on your own logic, the key item is `0.0.0.0` is not correct, you could try change both to `redis` to have a look. After make it work, you could find which is better for you, `ENV` or `Variable in CACHES`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I also want to add one more thing: In my redis.conf, I commented out # bind 127.0.0.1 -::1. and protected-mode no.